# arrays comparison

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to count duplicates in Ruby Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765368/how-to-count-duplicates-in-ruby-arrays)
>   [Ruby: Compare 2 arrays for matches, and count the number of match instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013880/ruby-compare-2-arrays-for-matches-and-count-the-number-of-match-instances)

I am starting to using **ruby** language. Suppose I have two arrays:

```
a=["A", "B", "C", "D"]
b=["C", "A", "X", "Y", "F"]
```

I would like to count the number of duplicated elements of the two arrays. To achieve this, the idea I came up with is like following:

```
nr_of_duplicates = (a- (a - b)).size
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013880/ruby-compare-2-arrays-for-matches-and-count-the-number-of-match-instances this might help u with the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765368/how-to-count-duplicates-in-ruby-arrays another one to achieve the same

Comment: "This is more like a discussion than a question" is an _instant_ reason for closure. I'll get rid of it for you since this question is _not_ a discussion, it's looking for the best approach.

Comment: If you are asking for a code-review, then the question should be on the code-review site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a method defined in Array class for this called '**&**':

```
ary & other_ary → new_ary

Set Intersection—Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates.

   [ 1, 1, 3, 5 ] & [ 1, 2, 3 ]   #=> [ 1, 3 ]
```