# How to group by count in array without using loop

Tags: ruby

```
arr = [1,2,1,3,5,2,4]
```

How can I count the array by group value with sorting? I need the following output:

```
x[1] = 2  
x[2] = 2  
x[3] = 1  
x[4] = 1  
x[5] = 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count duplicates in Ruby Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765368/how-to-count-duplicates-in-ruby-arrays)

Comment: Why without a loop? There's going to be a loop going on somewhere.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
x = arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
```

Comment: Many thanks michael and Terw. I like this very short. But, can you please briefly  explain the above short line. :).

Comment: `inject` "injects" an accumulator into an Enumerable, which in our case is a Hash with a default value of `0`. On every iteration, we add one to the value with the key of the current element (`e`). Finally we return the accumulator. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001494

Comment: The "inject" operation is often called "fold" in functional programming languages, which I think is a more intuitive name.

Comment: But that code doesn't sort hash. So in the end it's need more: Hash[#code here#.sort] or even sort_by

Comment: prefer `.each_with_object` over `inject` when building hashes versus arithmetic. See @sawa's answer below.

Comment: "Inject" is also known as reduce. I think that makes it really clear.

Comment: This *is* a *loop*.

Answer (score 59):

There is a short version which is in [`ruby 2.7 => Enumerable#tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally).

```rb
[1,2,1,3,5,2,4].tally  #=> { 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>1, 4=>1 }
```

Comment: `tally` doesn't accept block in 2.7 https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally

Answer (score 38):

**Only available under ruby 1.9**

Basically the same as [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5470797/2475008), but a slightly shorter way:

```
x = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e, h| h[e] += 1}
```

In similar situations,

- When the starting element is a **mutable** object such as an `Array`, `Hash`, `String`, you can use `each_with_object`, as in the case above.
- When the starting element is an **immutable** object such as `Numeric`, you have to use `inject` as below.

  `sum = (1..10).inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n} # => 55`

Comment: In terms of characters, it's longer. In terms of tokens, it's shorter. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Thanks @sawa. Absolutely it's very shorter and faster. Because, my actual array is mutable format and it holds a very large amount of data. thanks once again.

Comment: Though I've noticed with this approach that the values isn't in sorted order like the answer said.

Comment: This is the cleanest answer. `each_with_object` has been added to avoid `h[e] += 1 ; h`

Answer (score 22):

```
arr.group_by(&:itself).transform_values(&:size)
#=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>1, 4=>1}
```

Comment: A thing of beauty!

Answer (score 21):

Yet another - similar to others - approach:

```rb
result=Hash[arr.group_by{|x|x}.map{|k,v| [k,v.size]}]
```

1. Group by each element's value.
2. Map the grouping to an array of *[value, counter]* pairs.
3. Turn the array of paris into key-values within a Hash, i.e. accessible via `result[1]=2 ...`.

Comment: Cleaner and easier to understand than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Whenever you find someone asserting that something is the fastest on this type of primitive routine, I always find its interesting to confirm that because without confirmation most of us are really just guessing.  So I took all of the methods here and benchmarked them.

I took an array of 120 links I extracted from a web page that I needed to group by count and implemented all of these using a seconds = Benchmark.realtime do loop and got all the times.

Assume links is the name of the array I need to count:

```
#0.00077
seconds = Benchmark.realtime do
  counted_links = {}
  links.each { |e| counted_links[e] = links.count(e) if counted_links[e].nil?}
end
seconds

#0.000232
seconds = Benchmark.realtime do
  counted_links = {}
  links.sort.group_by {|x|x}.each{|x,y| counted_links[x] = y.size}
end

#0.00076
seconds = Benchmark.realtime do 
  Hash[links.uniq.map{ |i| [i, links.count(i)] }]
end

#0.000107 
seconds = Benchmark.realtime do 
  links.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, v| h[v] += 1; h}
end

#0.000109
seconds = Benchmark.realtime do 
  links.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e, h| h[e] += 1}
end

#0.000143
seconds = Benchmark.realtime do 
  links.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h, e| h[e] += 1 ; h }
end
```

And then a little bit of ruby to figure out the answer:

```
times = [0.00077, 0.000232, 0.00076, 0.000107, 0.000109, 0.000143].min
==> 0.000107
```

So the actual fastest method, ymmv of course, is:

```
links.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, v| h[v] += 1; h}
```

Comment: I think "leap in logic" befits your conclusion. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the benchmarks, this helped me select the quickest option, which is all i was interested in.

Comment: `#tally` is the fastest option now, unless you need to count based on some derived value, in which case the `each_with_object` option is faster than `map` plus `tally` for large arrays.

Answer (score 11):

```
x = Hash[arr.uniq.map{ |i| [i, arr.count(i)] }]
```

Latest Ruby has `to_h` method:

```
x = arr.uniq.map{ |i| [i, arr.count(i)] }.to_h
```

Comment: Michael Kohl beat me, but he's code should be faster. This code takes about twice as long

Comment: @fl00r..that is interesting..I thought this would be slower as it loops through and then again use `count` method on the array. Maybe using built in methods has their advantage. :)

Comment: @fl00r: Really? I originally had a version using `count`, but thought it wouldn't scale well with array length, so replaced it by my current answer. Can you run your benchmark with somewhat bigger array and compare again.

Comment: Not really. I was wrong. As far as this is `O(n2)` it is faster in benchmarks with small arrays, but it will increadibly slow with big arrays. My fault is I was testing present array in million cycle bench - so it was 20% faster.

Comment: @fl00r..yeah..definitely this would be slow for larger arrays.

Answer (score 6):

I am sure there are better ways,

```
>> arr.sort.group_by {|x|x}.each{|x,y| print "#{x} #{y.size}\n"}
1 2
2 2
3 1
4 1
5 1
```

assign x and y values to a hash as needed.

Comment: it is not necessary to `sort` before `group_by`. `arr.group_by {...}` will do the same thing

Comment: @user102008 The OP implied the results are to be presented in order. Not `[2,1].group_by {|x|x} #=> {2=>[2], 1=>[1]}` kurumi, what ways are better?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `group_by` returns a `Hash` which has no order. The order in which entries in a `Hash` is iterated is unpredictable.

Comment: @user102008, `group_by` [preserves order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378914/does-enumerables-group-by-preiserve-the-enumerables-order), at least in MRI 1.9+. AFAIK, it is not documented, but should be, as it's part of the spec.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The values corresponding to each key have an order; sorting might be relevant if you cared about that. But there is no order among the keys, for the very fact that the returned value is a `Hash`. So it would NOT have anything to do with `[2,1].group_by {|x|x} #=> {2=>[2], 1=>[1]}`

Comment: I assume you are aware that recent versions of Ruby maintain insertion order. As Dave Thompson puts it (Pickaxe, p71): "And, as of Ruby 1.9, you’ll find something that might be surprising: Ruby remembers the order in which you add items to a hash. When you subsequently iterate over the entries, Ruby will return them in that order. Assuming `Array.each` has not been redefined, I would think the reference I cited earlier (which gives the source code and spec for `group_by`) is definitive.

Answer (score 6):

Just for the record, I recently read about [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-tap) [here](http://phrogz.net/tap-vs-each_with_object). My solution would be:

`Hash.new(0).tap{|h| arr.each{|i| h[i] += 1}}`

The `#tap` method passes the caller to the block and then returns it. This is pretty handy when you have to incrementally build an array/hash.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it

```
arr = [1,2,1,3,5,2,4]

puts arr.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, v| h[v] += 1; h}
#=> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>1, 4=>1}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [1,2,1,3,5,2,4]
r = {}
arr.each { |e| r[e] = arr.count(e) if r[e].nil?}
```

Outputs

```
p r
#==> {1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>1, 5=>1, 4=>1}
```