# Why is Enumerable#each_with_object deprecated?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

According to [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_object), the Ruby method `Enumerable#each_with_object` is deprecated.

Unless it's mistaken (saying "deprecated on the latest stable version of Rails" makes me suspicious that maybe it's Rails' monkey-patching that's deprecated), why is it deprecated?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, that seems a bit weird.

Even Agile Rails writes somewhere:

> "The Ruby 1.9 `each_with_object` method was found to be so handy that the Rails crew backported it to Ruby 1.8 for you".

This seems like an error in APIdock ? I don't see any reason why it would be.

Comment: I agree, it's really handy. If it's deprecated I'll just add my own to every Ruby I find! :)

Comment: Funny, I think I just read this in the 1.9 Pick Axe book the other day.

Answer (score 51):

This is rather an answer to a denial of the presupposition of your question, and is also to make sure what it is.

---

The `each_with_object` method saves you extra key-strokes. Suppose you are to create a hash out of an array. With `inject`, you need an extra `h` in:

```
array.inject({}){|h, a| do_something_to_h_using_a; h} # <= extra `h` here
```

but with `each_with_object`, you can save that typing:

```
array.each_with_object({}){|a, h| do_something_to_h_using_a} # <= no `h` here
```

So it is good to use it whenever possible, but there is a restriction. As I also answered in "[How to group by count in array without using loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470725/how-to-group-by-count-in-array-without-using-loop/5475521#5475521)",

- When the initial element is a **mutable** object such as an `Array`, `Hash`, `String`, you can use `each_with_object`.
- When the initial element is an **immutable** object such as `Numeric`, you have to use `inject`:

  ```
  sum = (1..10).inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n} # => 55
  ```

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the clarification of the difference between each_with_object and inject!

Comment: According to [this source](http://www.bbs-software.com/blog/2013/11/22/rubys-injectreduce-and-each_with_object/), each_with_object does more than just save key strokes, it's actually a more efficient version of inject because it re-uses the same object for each iteration rather than creating a new one.

Comment: you do realize that the second version has 7 extra characters, right ? so when you say that `each_with_object` saves you keystrokes, I would expect the second version to have less chars. Not the case.

Comment: @CosminAtanasiu "save keystrokes" is your word, not mine.

Answer (score 13):

There's no note in the Ruby trunk source code, the method *is* still there (contrary to that page's claims), and there's been no talk of it on the mailing list that I can find.

APIdock is simply confused. The point where APIdock says it was deprecated is actually the earliest version with the method in the standard library (rather than just being an ActiveSupport backport extension), and Rails disables its version if you're using a Ruby that has the method, so APIdock appears to be confused by the method migrating between projects.