# What is an elegant way of modifying hashes inside an array within a nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, key-value

I would like to transform this

```
def some_process(k,v)
    return "#{v}_#{k}"
end

a_hash = {
    "i_love_hashes" => {
        "thing" => 20,
        "other_thing" => "0",
        "yet_another_thing" => "i disagree",
        "_peculiar_thing" => [
            {"count" => 30,
            "name" => "freddie"},
            {"count" => 15,
            "name" => "johhno"},
            {"count" => 12,
            "name" => "mohammed"},
        ]
    },
    "as_do_i" => {
       "thing" => 10,
       "other_thing" => "2",
       "yet_another_thing" => "i strongly agree",
       "_peculiar_thing" => [
           {"count" => 10,
           "name" => "frodo"},
           {"count" => 4,
           "name" => "bilbo"},
           {"count" => 2,
           "name" => "elizabeth"},
       ] 
    }
}
```

into this

```
{
"i_love_hashes"=>{
    "thing"=>20, 
    "other_thing"=>"0", 
    "yet_another_thing"=>"i disagree", 
    "_peculiar_thing"=> [
        {"count"=>30, "name"=>"freddie", :sinister_name=>"freddie_i_love_hashes"}, 
        {"count"=>15, "name"=>"johhno", :sinister_name=>"johhno_i_love_hashes"}, 
        {"count"=>12, "name"=>"mohammed", :sinister_name=>"mohammed_i_love_hashes"}
        ]}, 
"as_do_i"=>{
    "thing"=>10, 
    "other_thing"=>"2", 
    "yet_another_thing"=>"i strongly agree", 
    "_peculiar_thing"=>[
        {"count"=>10, "name"=>"frodo", :sinister_name=>"frodo_as_do_i"},
        {"count"=>4, "name"=>"bilbo", :sinister_name=>"bilbo_as_do_i"}, 
        {"count"=>2, "name"=>"elizabeth", :sinister_name=>"elizabeth_as_do_i"}
        ]
    }
}
```

this is the code I am currently using to achieve this

```
a_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),o|
  o.merge!({k =>
      v.each_with_object({}) do |(a,b),g|
        g.merge!({ a =>
          (b.is_a?(Array) ? b.collect {|x| x.merge({sinister_name: (some_process k, x["name"])})} : b)
          })
      end
    })
end
```

Ignoring the specific details of what is being returned by "some_process" (what is important is that it depends on the outer most key and the inner name values, in this example), are there any alternatives that would be considered more elegant?

Comment: Why `.each_with_object()` and not `inject()`?

Comment: @Phlip I would almost always use inject for this but the second answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481009/why-is-enumerableeach-with-object-deprecated) gives a credible reason why each_with_object is valid.

Comment: @Phlip: what would the equivalent inject-based version be?

Comment: It turns out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481009/why-is-enumerableeach-with-object-deprecated , that `each_with_object` is merely `inject` without the need to return the hash (in your case) at the end of each block.

Comment: given I can write your algorithm as `a_hash.each do |key, value|
         value['_peculiar_thing'].map do |h| 
          h.merge! :sinister_name => "#{ h['name'] }_i_love_hashes"
         end
       end`, if I don't mind stomping on your input `a_hash`, you could also dispense with `each_with_object` altogether and merely deep-clone `a_hash` before you start. if you mind it gets stomped on.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a recursive function?

```
def add_siniter(hash) 
  hash[:siniter_name] = "#{hash['name']}_i_love_hashes"
  hash
end

def format_hash(item)
  case item
    when Hash  then item.keys.each{|key| format_hash(item[key])}
    when Array then item.map!{|h| add_siniter(h)}
  end
end

format_hash(a_hash)
```

Comment: While I like the idea of a recursive method, the top level keys would need to be passed down, along with a depth parameter, to make it work, in this case.

Comment: Also, the format_hash method you've provided only appears to return an array of the two top-level keys, when run with the provided hash.