# How to replace all hash keys having a '.'?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and I would like to replace all hash keys so to change the hash from

```
h_before = {:"aaa.bbb" => 1, :c => 2, ...}
```

to

```
h_after = {:bbb => 1, :c => 2, ...}
```

That is, I would like to someway "demodulize" all hash keys having the `.`. How can I make that?

Comment: Please show the code you've written toward answering this question. It's better for us to work with something you've started, than it is for us to start from scratch and you shoehorn it into place.

Comment: If this were [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions), I would suggest `eval(h_before.gsub("aaa.",""))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h_before = {:"aaa.bbb" => 1, :c => 2}
h_after =
h_before.inject({}){|h, (k, v)| h[k.to_s.split(".").last.to_sym] = v; h}
# => {:bbb = > 1, :c => 2}
```

Comment: Can you change (explicit) names so that I understand what is what?

Comment: You are right but, for example, I don't understand the `h` to what refers in `h.keys.each{|k| h[k.to_s.split(".").last.to_sym] = h.delete(k)}`. `h` refers to the duplicated hash? Where?

Comment: What about `each_with_object` rather than `inject` to get rid of that pesky `;h` at the end?

Comment: I thought `each_with_object` was deprecated. But any solution should use `HashWithIndiferenceAccess`; this being a Rails-tagged question...

Comment: @Philip, re deprecation, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481009/why-is-enumerableeach-with-object-deprecated), especially sawa's and chuck's answers.

Answer (score 4):

[each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) is a cleaner and shorter approach than inject from the answer:

```
h_before.each_with_object({}){|(k, v),h| h[k.to_s.split(".").last.to_sym] = v}
=> {:bbb=>1, :c=>2}
```

Comment: I like this `each_with_object` one.. so +1

Answer (score 2):

Since there are a bunch of answers claiming to do the same thing, I thought it was time to post some benchmarks:

```
require 'fruity'

h_before = {:"aaa.bbb" => 1, :c => 2}

def cdub_test(hash)
  Hash[hash.map {|k, v| [k.to_s.gsub(/^.*\./,"").to_sym, v]}]
end

def matt_test(old_hash)
  Hash[old_hash.map { |k,v| [ k.to_s.sub(/.*\./,'').to_sym, v ] }]
end

class Hash
  require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access'
  def grep_keys(pattern)
    return inject(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new){|h, (k, v)|
      h[$1 || k] = v  if pattern =~ k.to_s ;  h }
  end
end

def phlip_test(hash)
  hash.grep_keys(/\.(\w+)$/)
end

def bjhaid_test(hash)
  hash.each_with_object({}){|(k, v),h| h[k.to_s.split(".").last.to_sym] = v}
end

def sawa_test(hash)
  hash.inject({}){|h, (k, v)| h[k.to_s.split(".").last.to_sym] = v; h}
end

compare do
    cdub   { cdub_test(h_before)   }
    matt   { matt_test(h_before)   }
    phlip  { phlip_test(h_before)  }
    bjhaid { bjhaid_test(h_before) }
    sawa   { sawa_test(h_before)   }
end
```

Which outputs:

```
Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
bjhaid is similar to sawa
sawa is faster than matt by 60.00000000000001% ± 10.0%
matt is faster than phlip by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0% (results differ: {:bbb=>1, :c=>2} vs {"bbb"=>1})
phlip is similar to cdub (results differ: {"bbb"=>1} vs {:bbb=>1, :c=>2})
```

Notice that phlip's code doesn't return the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

```
old_hash = {:"aaa.bbb" => 1, :c => 2 }
new_hash = Hash[old_hash.map { |k,v| [ k.to_s.sub(/.*\./,'').to_sym, v ] }]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3p448 :001 > hash = {:"aaa.bbb" => 1, :c => 2 }
 => {:"aaa.bbb"=>1, :c=>2} 

1.9.3p448 :002 > Hash[hash.map {|k, v| [k.to_s.gsub(/^.*\./,"").to_sym, v]}]
 => {:bbb=>1, :c=>2}
```

Comment: Can you write a `RegEx`, to extract `"bbb"` only from `:"aaa.bbb"`. Then code can be written as `Hash[hash.map {|k, v| [k.to_s[/your regex/].to_sym, v]}]`

Comment: I am asking you to do this,as I am sooooo week in `RegEx`. :)

Comment: I sense some sarcasm... The regex is within the gsub above will handle the gsub....  `/^.*\./`

Comment: That said, if you're serious...  The regex for your answer would be `/(?<=\.).*/` ... `hash.keys.first.to_s[/(?<=\.).*/] => "bbb"`

Comment: `sub` should be used instead of `gsub`. The first will only do one search and replace, unlike `gsub` which will try to find additional matches to replace. It's a minimal difference for short strings, but does add up over time. For long strings it can be a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

My `grep_keys` has never failed me here:

```
class Hash
  def grep_keys(pattern)
    return inject(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new){|h, (k, v)| 
      h[$1 || k] = v  if pattern =~ k.to_s ;  h }
  end
end
```

It returns a shallow-copy of the Hash, but only with the matched keys. If the input regular expression contains a `()` match, the method replaces the key with the matched value. (Note this might merge two or more keys, and discard all but a random value for them!) I use it all the time to cut up a Rails `param` into sub-params containing only the keys that some module needs.

`{:"aaa.bbb" => 1, :c => 2 }.grep_keys(/\.(\w+)$/)` returns `{"bbb"=>1}`.

This method upgrades your actual problem to "how to define a regexp that matches what you mean by 'having a ".".'"

Comment: You might want to compare your results to what the OP wanted.