# Better way to replace keys of a hash

Tags: ruby

I want to normalise a `Hash`'s keys using a normalisation function so that this hash

```
{"aType" => 1, "b_Type" => 2}
```

would be converted to

```
{:atype => 1, :btype => 2}
```

Here, the normalisation function removes underscores from the keys, downcases them, and makes them symbols.

I wrote the following using `map` (assume `normalize` is a normalisation method):

```
params = params.map {|k,v| {normalize(k) => v}}.inject(:merge)
```

Is there any better way to do this?

This question is related to a question "[How to replace all hash keys having a '.'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251633/how-to-replace-all-hash-keys-having-a)". I want to know the optimal (less verbose or faster) way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it

```
Hash[h.map {|k,v| [normalize(k), v] }]
```

Comment: Right, looks faster (I don't like `inject(:merge)` on performance point of view. Let me wait for other answers:)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how Rails does it (they extend `Hash` to make all keys strings in this case, but you could as easily put the method elsewhere).

```
def stringify_keys!
  keys.each do |key|
    self[key.to_s] = delete(key)
  end
  self
end
```

Though all of these approaches are reasonable, and there is likely not a substantial readability or performance difference for most uses.

Comment: This sounds great, if I use same in various locations and monkey-patching `Hash` is reasonable. Great answer. Unfortunately, For my current project, I need to avoid monkey patching and need 'in place' or one-liner solution, so I can't use this way:<  Let me decide which is the best answer later.. (regardless of whether I use the answer for my current project or not:)

Comment: It's reasonably clear how you could use this method without monkey-patching. Just make it take an argument and use that in the place of `self` (and call `delete` on it).

But no, it's not a one-liner.

Comment: Thank you. Code itself is not a issue. Where to place the monkey-patching code is the issue, especially I only need this functionality at one place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Rails application, or want to bring in ActiveSupport, you can use [ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) which allows you to use either `'key'` or `:key` to set or get a value from the hash

Comment: Thank you. I'm developing a rails application. But I need keys to be same in various locations (not only the hash itself) so I can't use this scheme. thanks anyway.