# How to count values in a array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes

```
[ {:name => "bob", :type => "some", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "ted", :type => "other", :product => "apples"},.... 
  {:name => "Will", :type => "none", :product => "oranges"} ]
```

and was wondering if there is a simple way to count the number of product's and store the count as well as the value in an array or hash.

I want the result to be something like:

```
@products =  [{"apples" => 2, "oranges => 1", ...}]
```

Comment: As per your need, I don't see any reason to keep the hash inside the Array. Is there any reason, then tell us.

Comment: Your expected result is not valid. It is impossible to get that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do as

```
array = [
  {:name => "bob", :type => "some", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "ted", :type => "other", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "Will", :type => "none", :product => "oranges"} 
]

array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |h1, h2| h2[h1[:product]] += 1 }
# => {"apples"=>2, "oranges"=>1}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I knew there was a way to do this easily in Ruby. I tried using inject but had no success. Thank you :)

Comment: for inject, try `array.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, item| hash[item[:product]] += 1; hash }`

Comment: @user2980830 Read *jvnil's* comment.

Comment: Thanks, is there any advantage of using inject vs. each_with_object? I see they will produce the same result.

Comment: here's a good explanation from @sawa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481009/why-is-enumerableeach-with-object-deprecated/5481396#5481396

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
array.group_by{|h| h[:product]}.map{|k,v| [k, v.size]}.to_h
# => {"apples"=>2, "oranges"=>1}
```

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly what the OP was looking for, this may be helpful to many. If you're just looking for the count of a specific product, you could do this:

```
array = [
  {:name => "bob", :type => "some", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "ted", :type => "other", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "Will", :type => "none", :product => "oranges"} 
]

array.count { |h| h[:product] == 'apples' }
# => 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count:

```
hashes = [
  {:name => "bob", :type => "some", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "ted", :type => "other", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "Will", :type => "none", :product => "oranges"}
]

hashes.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,o| h[o[:product]] += 1; h }
```

Or maybe...

```
hashes.instance_eval { Hash[keys.map { |k| [k,count(k)] }] }
```

I do not know which is the more performant, the latter seims weird to read though.

Comment: Can you try the code you have given in IRB? `hashes.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |h,(_,value)| h[value] += 1 }`.. It is completely wrong.

Comment: I was trying to use inject as i have used it before to count items but have never seen this "(_,value)", thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
items =[ {:name => "bob", :type => "some", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "ted", :type => "other", :product => "apples"},
  {:name => "Will", :type => "none", :product => "oranges"} ]

 counts = items.group_by{|x|x[:product]}.map{|x,y|[x,y.count]}
 p counts #=> [["apples", 2], ["oranges", 1]]
```

Then if you need it as a Hash just do:

```
 Hash[counts]
```