# Does Enumerable's group_by preserve the Enumerable's order?

Tags: arrays, ruby, enumerable

Does [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) preserve the original order within each value? When I get this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].group_by{|i| i % 2}
# => {1=>[1, 3, 5], 0=>[2, 4]}
```

is it guaranteed that, for example, the array `[1, 3, 5]` contains the elements in this order and not, for example `[3, 1, 5]`?

Is there any description regarding this point?

I am not mentioning the order between the keys `1` and `0`. That is a different issue.

Comment: `Enumerable` uses `each` to traverse the collection. Changing the order would require extra effort.

Comment: But previously, I learned that the reminescent `Enumerable#sort` is not stable. So I couldn't be sure about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, `Enumerable#group_by` preserves input order.

Here's the implementation of that method in MRI, from https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c:

```
static VALUE
enum_group_by(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE hash;

    RETURN_SIZED_ENUMERATOR(obj, 0, 0, enum_size);

    hash = rb_hash_new();
    rb_block_call(obj, id_each, 0, 0, group_by_i, hash);
    OBJ_INFECT(hash, obj);

    return hash;
}

static VALUE
group_by_i(RB_BLOCK_CALL_FUNC_ARGLIST(i, hash))
{
    VALUE group;
    VALUE values;

    ENUM_WANT_SVALUE();

    group = rb_yield(i);
    values = rb_hash_aref(hash, group);
    if (!RB_TYPE_P(values, T_ARRAY)) {
        values = rb_ary_new3(1, i);
        rb_hash_aset(hash, group, values);
    }
    else {
        rb_ary_push(values, i);
    }
    return Qnil;
}
```

`enum_group_by` calls `group_by_i` on each array (`obj`) element in order. `group_by_i` creates a one-element array (`rb_ary_new3(1, i)`) the first time a group is encountered, and pushes on to the array thereafter (`rb_ary_push(values, i)`). So the input order is preserved.

Also, RubySpec requires it. From https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/core/enumerable/group_by_spec.rb:

```
it "returns a hash with values grouped according to the block" do
  e = EnumerableSpecs::Numerous.new("foo", "bar", "baz")
  h = e.group_by { |word| word[0..0].to_sym }
  h.should == { :f => ["foo"], :b => ["bar", "baz"]}
end
```

Comment: This depends on the implementation of `each` which is mapped via `id_each` in the call to `rb_block_call`

Answer (score 9):

More specifically, `Enumerable` calls `each` so it depends on how `each` is implemented and whether `each` yields the elements in the original order:

```
class ReverseArray < Array
  def each(&block)
    reverse_each(&block)
  end
end

array = ReverseArray.new([1,2,3,4])
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]

array.group_by { |i| i % 2 }
#=> {0=>[4, 2], 1=>[3, 1]}
```

Comment: Thanks for making clear that it calls `each`. `reverse_each` would not make sense if the order of `each` were arbitrary. Doesn't the existence of `reverse_each` imply that `each` preserves the order (unless it is overwritten by the user)?

Comment: It's just an example. `Array#each` of course yields the elements [in the same order](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#class-Array-label-Iterating+over+Arrays): *"In case of Array’s each, all elements in the Array instance are yielded to the supplied block in sequence."* But other classes could implement it differently, for example `Hash` in Ruby 1.8. Therefore, `group_by` can't guarantee any order, it depends entirely on `each`.

Comment: so, in conclusion, `group_by` preserves order when dealing with arrays, but not necessarily in other structures.