# Array of arrays merge in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have an array of arrays like this: `[['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]`.

So if I will add to the existing array this array `['Area1', 33441]` I want either to merge the array like this `[['Area1', 12345, 33441], ['Area2', 54321]]` or to display the information like this:

`Area1: 12345, 33441
 Area2: 54321`

Does anyone have any idea if is this possible in rails? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like a Hash might be the more appropriate data structure here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Hash#merge!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge%21) method with a block for that:

```
initial = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]].to_h
initial.merge!({'Area1' => 1212 }) { |_,v1,v2| [v1,v2].flatten }
#=> {"Area1"=>[12345, 1212], "Area2"=>54321}
```

and if you want the result to be an array, you can use

```
initial.merge!({'Area1' => 1212 }) { |_,v1,v2| [v1,v2].flatten }.to_a
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect for my case. Thank you a lot @xlembouras !

Comment: I expect the return value would be easier to work with if `"Area2"=>54321` were `"Area2"=>[54321]` (to be consistent with arrays of two or more values). For example, `initial = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]; (initial + [['Area1', 1212]]).each_with_object({}) { |(area,nbr),h| h.merge!(area=>[nbr]) { |_,v1,v2| v1 + v2 } } #=> {"Area1"=>[12345, 1212], "Area2"=>[54321]}`. (Readers: both x's answer and this variant use the form of [Hash#merge!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21) that employs a block to compute the values of keys present in both hashes being merged.)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not using the right data structure. You are better of using a Hash for the purpose that looks like this:

```
  areas = {
    'Area1' => [12345], 
    'Area2' => [54321]
  }
```

But following up your structure you can do something like this:

```
  areas = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]
  new_area = ['Area1', 33441]

  areas.map { |area|
    if area.first == new_area.first
      area + [new_area.last]
    else
      area
    end
  end
```

Also just so it is easier for you to find this in the future, this has not thing to do with Rails (the web framework that sits on top of Ruby) but with Ruby itself (the programming language).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to stick with arrays, then try something like:

```
arr1 = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]
arr2 = ['Area1', 33441]
arr1.inject([]){|r,i| r.push(i[0] == arr2[0] ? i.push(arr2[1]) : i)}
```

In console:

```
2.3.1 :001 > arr1 = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]
 => [["Area1", 12345], ["Area2", 54321]] 
2.3.1 :002 > arr2 = ['Area1', 33441]
 => ["Area1", 33441] 
2.3.1 :003 > arr1.inject([]){|r,i| r.push(i[0] == arr2[0] ? i.push(arr2[1]) : i)}
 => [["Area1", 12345, 33441], ["Area2", 54321]]
```

Looking at polmiro's answer, I prefer his `map` to my `inject`. They are essentially the same, I believe. Except that `map` does the work for you of creating a new `array` whereas with `inject` you have to pass in the new `array`. And, `map` is doing an implicit `push` whereas, with `inject`, again, you have to do the work yourself. Nice job, polmiro!

Here's the one-line version of his answer (if you like that sort of thing):

```
arr1.map{|a| a[0] == arr2[0] ? a << arr2[1] : a}
```

And again in console:

```
2.3.1 :001 > arr1 = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]
 => [["Area1", 12345], ["Area2", 54321]] 
2.3.1 :002 > arr2 = ['Area1', 33441]
 => ["Area1", 33441] 
2.3.1 :003 > arr1.map{|a| a[0] == arr2[0] ? a << arr2[1] : a}    
 => [["Area1", 12345, 33441], ["Area2", 54321]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For

```
arr = [['Area1', 12345], ['Area2', 54321]]
to_add = ['Area1', 1212]
```

we may compute the desired array as follows:

```
(arr + [to_add]).group_by(&:first).map { |k,v| [k, *v.map(&:last)] }
  #=> [["Area1", 12345, 1212], ["Area2", 54321]]
```

The first step, using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) produces the following hash:

```
(arr + [to_add]).group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"Area1"=>[["Area1", 12345], ["Area1", 1212]],
  #    "Area2"=>[["Area2", 54321]]}
```

For this to work we must be sure that `group_by` produces a hash whose keys are ordered the same as `arr.map(&:first).uniq #=> ["Area1", "Area2"]`. (Note that [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) preserves order by keeping the first instance of each element). See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24378914/does-enumerables-group-by-preserve-the-enumerables-order). As `Array#each` generates the elements of `arr + [to_add]` in order, and the insertion order of hash keys is maintained for Ruby versions 1.9+, we can be assured that the result will have elements in the correct order.

Others have argued that representing the data as a hash may be a better data model. That may be, but the question does not provide enough information about how the return value is to be used to be certain about that. I've therefore provided only what was asked for by the question.