# Concise way of reducing a Ruby array to the count of unique values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, count, unique

I have a Ruby array that looks something like this:

```
animals = %w(dog cat bird cat dog bird bird cat)
```

I need to get a count of each unique item in the array. I could do something like this:

```
dogs = 0
cats = 0
birds = 0

animals.each do |animal|
  dogs += 1 if animal == 'dog'
  cats += 1 if animal == 'cat'
  birds += 1 if animal == 'bird'
end
```

...but this approach is too verbose. What is the most concise way of calculating these unique counts in Ruby?

Comment: Check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470725/how-to-group-by-count-in-array-without-using-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess what you're looking for is [`count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-count):

```
animals = %w(dog cat bird cat dog bird bird cat)
dogs = animals.count('dog') #=> 2
cats = animals.count('cat') #=> 3
birds = animals.count('bird') #=> 3
```

Comment: Oh, interesting! I didn't know that count accepts an argument!

Comment: +1, i didn't know that either

Answer (score 2):

```
animals.uniq.map { |a| puts a, animals.count(a)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it using `group_by`

```
animals = %w(dog cat bird cat dog bird bird cat)
hash = animals.group_by {|i| i}
hash.update(hash) {|_, v| v.count}

#=> hash = {"dog"=>2, "cat"=>3, "bird"=>3}
```

Comment: Your last line is very cool. I'm familiar with the form of `update` that takes a block, but I haven't seen it with a hash `merge!`d into itself. You might consider writing the block variables as `|_,v,_|`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to store the counts in a hash like so:

```
animals = %w(dog cat bird cat dog bird bird cat)
animal_counts = {}
animals.each do |animal|
  if animal_counts[animal]
    animal_counts[animal] += 1
  else
    animal_counts[animal] = 1
  end
end
```

This stores each unique item in the array as a key with they count as the value. It improves upon your code because it doesn't require advance knowledge of the contents of the array.

Comment: Well, this seems like an overkill to me. You say you don't need an advance knowledge of the contents of the array, I agree, that's right. But, how will you access the count of `dog`, `cat`, or `bird` if you don't pass them as key in your newly created Hash?

Comment: You can simplify this to: `animals.each_with_object({}) {|a,c| c[a] = (c[a] ||= 0)+1} => {"dog"=>2, "cat"=>3, "bird"=>3}`.