# Middleman - Unique Categories with amount of posts in each sorted

Tags: ruby, middleman, middleman-4

I want to get the Unique categories from my blog posts - but also return the count of how many posts are in each category

Currently I have this

```
= blog( 'portfolio' ).articles.map { | r | r.data.category }.uniq.sort
```

I guess I need to remove the Uniq and Sort and do some Group.by then sort.

Any help appreciated to get this one liner sorted and fast

Cheers

Ian

Answer (score 0):

This Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470725/how-to-group-by-count-in-array-without-using-loop) should answer your question too. It shows a number of ways that you could get a Hash mapping from category to count.